# Error pasting .html to assets folder

Tags: android, android-studio, android-assets

I have a problem pasting `.html` files into assets folder in android studio. whenever i paste it and run my code i get the `red R error`. Is there any way to properly import my `html` files?.  Because in eclipse it worked for me when importing. Please help me.

Comment: do a project clean after dropping the files

Comment: do you use assets-folder or res/raw?

Comment: i also did the gradle sync, but the red R still there. I am using the assets folder and my html files are less than 1mb.